# How do I create a 3D printable stl file?

Tags: sketchup

Ok, I finally have a good sketch of a teacup I want to 3D print.  The next step is to export the sketch to a 3D printable stl file.  I have tried using CADspan Pro (which crashes when I click "process" at the resurfacing step) and a `skp_to_dxf.rb` plugin (which does export an extension-less file (I am assuming a stl), a file which does not validate when I upload it to Shapeways or Ponoko) but with no luck.

**So my question is this, how do I create a high resolution 3D printable stl file from my existing skp file?**  [Here is my skp file](https://sketchup-a-googleproductforums-com.googlegroups.com/attach/d85f90ccd069563e/teacup.skp?gda=T18nQUcAAAAz-vHkIy_YLYKJOITrH9JnXVGFar2Q_kFh8_kXhGYdAtHPxQ3x-303qy9pcE8dq4gbQwFxJw55cVwemAxM-EWmeV4duv6pDMGhhhZdjQlNAw&pli=1&view=1&part=4).

Comment: I think you might want to ask this question on a different site - this does not seem to be related to GIS.

Comment: http://www.guitar-list.com/download-software/convert-sketchup-skp-files-dxf-or-stl

Answer (score 0):

There's an open source project from SketchUp with and import and export function for STL: https://github.com/SketchUp/sketchup-stl/

(Note, the "latest and greatest is available" which the readme claims, isn't - the source has many changes and fixes.)